# Metamask shows me 18 token sent, Etherscan shows 0 token sent

Tags: metamask, etherscan

I'm lost...
Metamask show me :

[image]

While Etherscan shows me 0 SNX :

[image]

What am I doing wrong???

Comment: Search for the transaction has in other block explorers like etherchain.org.